# AIX sed - find exact match and replace

Tags: unix, sed, aix, ksh

I need to use sed on AIX to find and replace exact match of a string.

as an example we have a like like below

```
LogicalVolume hdisk1 hdisk10
```

and I have 2 variables

```
old_disk=hdisk1
new_disk=hdisk50
```

Here is the sed command I would like to use

```
sed "s/"$old_disk"/"$new_disk"/" file1.txt \> file2.txt
```

The outcome that I get looks like below

```
LogicalVolume hdisk50 hdisk500
```

instead of

```
LogicalVolume hdisk50 hdisk10
```

Unfortunately < and > do not work on AIX and I don't know how to replace the exact match of variable old_disk. I also tried  ' and " around the variable, but it doesn't work neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that perl is available by default on AIX, I'd recommend using it to avoid using disk-related commands with mistaken data!

```bash
old_disk=hdisk1
new_disk=hdisk50
export old_disk new_disk
perl -pe 's/\b$ENV{"old_disk"}\b/$ENV{"new_disk"}/g' < file1.txt > file2.txt
```

This sets the same two variables as your example, then exports them into the environment so that the upcoming perl command can access them. The perl command simply searches and replaces any of the "old_disk" values with "new_disk" values, but restricts the search text by requiring it to have a word boundary on both sides. A word boundary is a change from a word character (alphanumeric and _) to a non-word character (or vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

The sed command is *possibly*

```bash
sed 's/\([[:space:]]\|^\)'"$old_disk"'\([[:space:]]\|$\)/\1'"$new_disk"'\2/' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

But I don't have an AIX environment to test on.

That looks for old_disk, preceded by whitespace or start of line and followed by whitespace or end of line.

Comment: It's clear why the perl answer is preferable.

Comment: tested this just now on an AIX box (had a window open from before); it doesn't replace "hdisk1" (the input is unchanged). I'm not savvy enough with sed to say why it failed :/

Comment: looks like if I replace the whole `[[:space:]]|^` with just a plain old space, it works ... looking more like the alternation maybe

Comment: The line is prefixed with "`LogicalVolume`" so the `^` won't be effective here. I still can't get the `([[:space:]]\|$` alternation to work. I think you'd have to hack around it with two expressions (one for mid-line matches and one for EOL matches)

Comment: different seds may or may not need the escape before the pipe and/or parentheses